# Managing Background App Refresh

Tags: ios

I have made a Newsstand app in iOS. How can I bring the app to foreground automatically once Background App Refresh is done?

Comment: You can't, only the user can do that

Answer (score 0):

You could trigger a user-visible [notification](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201925) that new content was ready, and it'd be up to them to click on it, or if they feel that's not helpful disable notifications for your app.